# Thinktecture Identity Server 3 Asp.Net Identity Sample, constantly getting 401 authorization denied

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3, thinktecture

I am trying to get the Asp.Net Identity Sample of the Identity Server working in my Web Api project, and a beginner I am trying to work on getting tokens and sending request to APIs using the the bearer tokens.

So using fiddler, I can send a request to the `https://localhost:44333/core/connect/token` with the following content: `client_id=roclient&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=bob&password=mypass&scope=read write offline_access` and it works fine, I get the access token and the refresh token.

Then I have a Web Api project in my solution, which has the code to use the bearer token:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44333",
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,

            RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1" }
        });
```

and a test controller in which an api is protected using the `[Authorize]` decorator.

As I said, fetching the token works fine, but when I use fiddler to send the request to the api I always get "401 authorization denied..." thing.

What I put in my fiddler request is of course:

`Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImE...`

Am I doing anythign wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Token request, you are requesting the read and write scope. Your api checks for the api1 scope. This cannot work.

Comment: I changed the token request to include the "read", "write" and "offline_access" scope. How do I make the method in the API controller part of those scopes? Because I am still getting the 401.

Comment: I really appreciate more detailed explanation, I am having a hard time understanding the IdentityServer from scratch using the documentation :(

Comment: You are requiring a scope named "api1" in your api. The token (at least telling from your request) does not include that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I've modified your sample so it will work for you:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new 
IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://localhost:44333",
    ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,

    RequiredScopes = new[] { "read", "write" } // scopes
});
```